# Show that the map of $L^1(\Bbb R)\cap L^2(\Bbb R)$ into $L^2(\Bbb R)$ defined by $f\mapsto \hat{f}$ is continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am doing self-study on Fourier analysis and I have the following questions. Could anyone give an elementary proof?
Consider the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ of $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$ defined by $$\hat{f}(\xi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-i\xi x}dx, \qquad \text{for $\xi\in\Bbb R$}.$$

(1) Show that if $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)\cap L^2(\Bbb R)$ then $\hat{f}\in L^2(\Bbb R)$.

(2) Show that the map of $L^1(\Bbb R)\cap L^2(\Bbb R)$ into $L^2(\Bbb R)$ defined by $f\mapsto \hat{f}$ is continuous with respect to the $L^2$-norm.

Comment: These are not very straightforward proofs and you shouldn't try to prove them on your own. A good reference is Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first step in  the proof of the Plancherel Theorem (it's the *main* step, so much so that people sometimes call this result itself the Plancherel Theorem). As suggested, an excellent reference is Rudin *Real and Complex Analysis*. Or Folland *Real Analysis* for a different argument, or any other text that includes beginning Fourier analysis.

The standard proofs are very slick, but they have a fairly high how-would-anyone-think-of-that factor. Here's an outline of another argument, that may or may not make more sense. Note it's just an outline - there are some major details omitted, but regardless it may serve to make the result at least plausible:

For $P>0$ define $$f_P(x)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}f(x+nP).$$Then $f_P$ has period $P$; hence it has a Fourier series. You can figure out the coefficients in terms of $\hat f$; now the $P$-periodic verion of the Parseval Theorem shows that $$\int_{-P/2}^{P/2}|f_P|^2=\frac cP\sum_{k\in \Bbb Z}\left|\hat f\left(\frac kP\right)\right|^2,$$where $c$ is a certain constant, $1/\sqrt\pi$ or $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ or something. (Different authors define $\hat f$ differently, hence would get different values of $c$ here...)

So far filling in the details is routine. Although the last step is quite plausible, it's where the details become not quite so trivial: If you let $P\to\infty$ you obtain$$||f||_2=c||\hat f||_2.$$